# How to deploy a ember-cli app with a grunt task?

Tags: ember.js, gruntjs, ember-cli, broccolijs

When I want to deploy my app to my enviroment I have to create a single file in a specific, containing the hole app (most of it BASE64 encoded) and import that file into a proprietary application.

I've created a grunt task that can easily generate that file form a folder. So I'm looking for a way to just type something into the console and then it should execute `ember build` and my script.

The simplest way to do this is just to create a brand new `Gruntfile.js` nearby the existing `Brocfile.js` and a batch file to run first `grunt` and then `ember build`.

A better way would be if I could call `ember build` from my gruntfile. Is there a way to do this?

Or, even better, is there a way to inject a grunt into the `ember build`? That would be awesome!

To be clear, broccoli is not the right tool for that! Its not a build step, but a deployment step! So I want to use the task runner, not the build tool.

Thanks!

Comment: Use bash or whatever MS Windows alternative is. Using Grunt alongside of Broccoli is _fine_. Personally I would write my build step with BASH and integrate it with Broccoli.

Comment: Well, is there a way to use the grunt-brocolli to call he `ember build`?

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use [`grunt-exec`](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec) to execute `ember build`, as part of a chain of grunt build tasks.

It allows you to execute arbitrary shell commands.

Something like the following might work:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  exec: {
    ember_build: {
      command: 'ember build'
    }
  }
});
```

and then execute with `grunt exec:ember_build` or as part of a larger task. (Note that I haven't tried this, but it should work!)

This might be slight overkill, you could just [chain your console commands](https://superuser.com/questions/235761/how-do-i-chain-commands-on-the-console):

```
ember build && grunt
```